# specify an alias for pytest to run a specific test in pytest.ini file

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fastapi

I would like to set up the pytest.ini file so that when I run for example :
`pytest end2end`, the command that is actually run is

```
pytest tests/end2end/*.py
```

Is there any way I could set this up in the pytest ini file?

I tried changing the testpaths but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to just run `pytest .tests/end2end` as that is already supported

There is multiple ways of doing this.

1. You can actually do it using the {posargs} function.
   Example from TOX: `pytest .tests/{posargs}.py`
2. Changing the default test path. This can be done in the ini file:
   https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths